# Confused about arrangements on a word

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to do this problem from "The Probability Tutoring Book" by Carol Ash.

> If the letters in ILLINOIS are arranged at random, find the probability that the permutation begins or ends with L.

My attempt:

We'll first find the total number of permutations.
Total Permutations: $\frac {8!}{(2!)(3!)}$

My reasoning for that total is we can arrange the eight letters in ILLINOIS $8!$ times. Since there are two L's and three I's, any arrangement where we just swap the I's with each other or the L's with each other, we have the same string(i.e. I$L_1L_2$INOIS is the same as I$L_2L_1$INOIS.)

Now I'll go about using the inclusion and exclusion principle to find the probability that our string begins with L or ends with L.

Total strings that begin with L: $\frac {7!}{(2!)(3!)}$

Where I use the same reasoning as above, but this time I fix the first letter to be "L" and can permute the other letters $7!$ ways

I use the same reasoning for the total strings that end with L : $\frac {7!}{(2!)(3!)}$

Now I take care of double counting, the total number of strings with both L as the first and last letter is $\frac {6!}{(2!)(3!)}$. Again, I applied the same reasoning as above.

Putting everything together,

$$P(begins\ or\ ends\ with\ L) = (\frac {1}{\frac {8!}{(2!)(3!)}}) * (\frac {7!}{(2!)(3!)} + \frac {7!}{(2!)(3!)} - \frac {6!}{(2!)(3!)}) = \frac {13}{56}$$

However, according to the answers, the correct answer is $\frac {26}{56}$, so I'm off by a factor or 2.

A possible reasoning could be that I$L_1L_2$INOIS is ***NOT*** the same as I$L_2L_1$INOIS. Why would this be?

Attempting this again on my differently,

$P(first\ letter\ is\ L) = P(last \ letter\ is\ L) = \frac {2}{8}$ since there are 2 L's of 8 letters

$P(first\ letter\ is\ L \cap last \ letter\ is\ L) = \frac{2}{8}\frac{1}{7}$ since there are 2 L's for the first letter and then they'll be 1 L for the last letter.

Putting everything together:

$P(first\ letter\ is\ L \cup last \ letter\ is\ L) = \frac{2}{8} + \frac {2}{8} -  \frac{2}{8}\frac{1}{7} = \frac {26}{56}$ which concurs with the answer in the book.

But I'm still struggling to figure out why my original answer was wrong. Did I undercount?

Comment: Wait but L1_ _ _ _ _ _ L2 is the same as  L2_ _ _ _ _ _ L1, so we should divide by two... no?

Comment: Oh! Are you saying that L_1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _  and L_2  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ each have arrangements (7! / 3!) because I specifically pick one of them to be at the start

Comment: But that still leaves me a few short since now I have $\frac {(2!)(7!)}{3!} - \frac {6!}{2!3!}$, I feel that the second fraction needs to be multiplied by two, so get the factor of two that I'm behind by.

Comment: An easier method would be to use the probability that it doesn't begin or end in an $L$. Namely find the answer as$$1-\frac{\binom{6}{2}\cdot6!/3!}{8!/(2!\cdot3!)}$$

Comment: Sorry, I really don't mean to be difficult, but aren't I making sure that the L's are not in the first and last position for the subtracting term. I'm choosing where they are not, right?

Comment: The number of ways to rearrange the $7$ letters $\{I,I,I,L,N,O,S\}$ is $7!/3!$. This equals the number of rearrangements starting (or ending) in $L$ because we just add the remaining $L$ to any of these arrangements. Although adding these double counts the cases with $L$ at the start and end. The number of ways to rearrange the $6$ letters $\{I,I,I,N,O,S\}$ is $6!/3!$. This equals the number of rearrangements starting and ending in $L$ because we just add the two $L$s to the start and end of any of these arrangements.

Comment: Just to be clear, the arrangement I L_2L_1 INOIS is the same as I L_1L_2 INOIS right?

Comment: Yes. I don't see where this arrangement comes from though.

Comment: Oh yes, there definitely not very relevant in this problem. I just want to know that the L's are not distinct.

Answer (score 2):

You made the error when you calculate the total strings that start with $L$.

As you said, we can fix one $L$ in the front of the string. For example, $LILINOIS$. However, you calculated $\frac{7!}{2!3!}$ when it should be just $\frac{7!}{3!}$. This is because out of the seven remaining letters, all are distinct except for the $3$ I's. You would not divide by $2$ for the $2$ L's, since you've already fixed one in place. You can basically think that the first $L$ isn't even there, since you've already fixed it into position. No matter what permutation, it will always stay there. Same thing for the ending letter $L$ and the case of both starting and ending with $L$.

Everything else is correct. As expected, when calculated you get $\frac{26}{56}$ (or simplified, $\frac{13}{28}$).

Hope that helped,

-FruDe